# How do I get data items from a complex Nusoap Object coming into php webservice

Tags: c#, php, arrays, web-services, nusoap

I'm passing a a complex object that is defined on the nusoap server side.
I'm able to declare and access all areas of the objects that are declared over on the nusoap server side after I adding the webservice to my c# client. as seen below.

```
public void sendArrayOfMHObjects()
    {
        //Steps: Create WS Instance, then create send and recieve objects defined on WS end
        masterH.mhserver mh = new masterH.mhserver();
        masterH.HarvestObject objRequest = new masterH.HarvestObject();
        masterH.ResponseObject objResponse = new masterH.ResponseObject();

        masterH.Stuffs[] stuffsArray = new masterH.Stuffs[2];

     //   stuffsArray[0].id = 4;

        //Populate and request Object 
        objRequest.responseCode = 34;  
        objRequest.responseMessage = "Whats up docs";


        masterH.Stuffs arrayObject = new masterH.Stuffs();
        arrayObject.id = 6;
         arrayObject.name = "John";

          masterH.Stuffs arrayObject2 = new masterH.Stuffs();
        arrayObject2.id = 7;
         arrayObject2.name = "Johnny boy";

         stuffsArray[0] = arrayObject;
         stuffsArray[1] = arrayObject2;

         objRequest.stuffArray =stuffsArray;


        //Pick up response and display it
        objResponse = mh.sendHarvest(objRequest);

        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Response Code: " + objResponse.responseCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Response Message: " + objResponse.responseMessage);
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    }
```

I can verify that the data is getting to the php webservice because I have a response object that is traversed in order to verfiy the data is there on the c# client side.
The problem I have is that I cannot access the array objects on the php side when the object arrives. This is what I have on the php side:
    $server = new soap_server(); $server->configureWSDL("mh-server", "urn:mh-server");

```
class ResponseObject {
    public $responseCode = -1;
    public $responseMessage = 'Unknown error!';
//    public $stuffArray = NULL;
}   

class HarvestObject {
public $responseCode = -1;
public $responseMessage = 'Unknown error!';
public $stuffArray = NULL;
}   


class StuffsArray {
public $stuffs = NULL;
}  


class Stuffs{
public $id = 23;
public $name = "Larry";
}  

$myNamespace = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];


$server->register("getStuffs", array(), 
array('return' => 'tns:ResponseObject'),$myNamespace,  $myNamespace."#getStuffs",
'rpc',  'encoded', 'Fetch array of Stuffs.'
);                                                          


$server->register("sendStuffs", array('TheList' => 'tns:ResponseObject'),   array('return' => 'tns:ResponseObject'), $myNamespace, 

$myNamespace."#sendStuffs",'rpc', 'encoded', 
'Send array of Stuffs.'
);                                                                      


$server->register("sendHarvest", array('HarvestData' => 'tns:HarvestObject'), array('return' => 'tns:ResponseObject'), $myNamespace, 
$myNamespace."#sendHarvest",    'rpc', 'encoded', 'Send Harvest Object.'
);                                                                      



////////////////////////////////////////////////////WEBSERVICE    
STRUCTURES////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////              

////////Response Structure////////////
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('ResponseObject',  'complexType', 'struct', 'all',  '', 
array('responseCode' => array('type' => 'xsd:int'), 
'responseMessage' => array(     'type' => 'xsd:string')
         )  );              

////////Request Structures////////////////////
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('HarvestObject',  'complexType', 
'struct', 'all',  '',   array('responseCode' => array('type' => 'xsd:int'),
'responseMessage' => array(   'type' => 'xsd:string'), 
'stuffArray'   => array(     'type' => 'tns:StuffsArray' ) )  );                

$server->wsdl->addComplexType('StuffsArray', 'complexType', 'array',
'','SOAP-   ENC:Array', array(), array( array('ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:Stuffs[]' ) ),'tns:Stuffs'  );         

$server->wsdl->addComplexType('Stuffs','complexType','struct','all','', 
array( 'id' =>   array('name' => 'id', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
'name' => array('name' => 'name', 'type' => 'xsd:string') )  );  






$server->service(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '');
```

/////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    //EXPOSED WEBSERVICE   METHODS//////////////////////////////////
    /////

```
function sendHarvest($harvestTemp) {

$harvestObject= new HarvestObject();
$harvestObject= $harvestTemp;
$harvestArray = array();
$harvestArray=$harvestObject->stuffArray;

$harvestItems = new Stuffs();

$responseObject = new ResponseObject();
$responseObject->responseCode=0;
$responseObject->responseMessage= $tempID.$tempName;    


return $responseObject;
}
```

At this point I've tried just about everything, and the last response I got was a null value being retured when I try to just build a concatenated string with the elements I want to extract. The items I need from the incoming array of objects are the id and name values.
Please help if you can thanks.